# Sonar analysis prior to code check in

Tags: java, sonarqube, analysis, sourceanalyser

I need to run Sonar analysis on Java file before committing code to svn. Is there any mechanism to ensure that code having sonar issues doesn't gets checked into svn unless all sonar issues get resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done if the SVN supports hooks or alike.

For example, Git allows writing hooks for the commits/push/[receive](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)[server side] ;

- First download [sonarscanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)
- Create a git pre-push hook on the developer's machine to run sonarscanner
- run sonarscanner and you will see the result on the stdout.

  if sonar-scanner  | grep '[ ]+[0-9]* blocker$' then 
     exit 1 
  else 
       exit 0 
  fi

Using this you can decide whether to accept or not the checkin (if there are blockers etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. The long answer is that you can come close.

Take a look at http://www.sonarlint.org/, for in-IDE code scanning. Then have a look at [pull request analysis](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) which should flag new issues. It's then up to the human reviewer to accept or reject the PR.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that we are using Eclipse ide (Luna) with the sonarlint plugin. The requirement is to prohibit code check in if major and critical sonar issues are present in the file to be checked in.